# php incorrectly echoes content outside tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

This is my first post on StackOverflow, thanks to the community for being such a great resource!

I have some PHP code in a WordPress template as follows:

```
echo '<div class="thumbnail">'; echo the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>';
echo '<h2>'. the_title() .'</h2>';
echo '<h2>Testing echo</h2>';
echo '<div>'. the_excerpt() .'</div>';
```

The first line is parsed correctly, with `the_post_thumbnail()` content inside the `<div>` tags

The second line is parsed incorrectly, with `the_title()` immediately preceding the `<h2>` tags, and, thus, not parsed as an `<h2>` heading.

The third line is parsed correctly, as an `<h2>` heading.

The fourth line is again parsed incorrectly, with `the_excerpt()` content immediately preceding the `<div>` tags, and, thus, not parsed as a `<div>`.

The relevant View Source, simplified for readability:

```
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="myimage.jpg"></div>
My title<h2></h2>
<h2>Testing echo</h2>
<p>My excerpt</p><div></div>
```

The project in question is an Isotope masonry page using jQuery, based on the Roots startup theme.
After Googling around the only possible lead I found is that it might be some sort of [shortcode] issue?
Scratching my brains out on this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the_title` and `the_excerpt` donot return the title, they directly echo it to the output buffer. This is why the title appears before <h2> tags
You can use the following variation for a quick hack

```
echo '<h2>';the_title();echo '</h2>';
```

Or even better

```
the_title("<h2>","</h2>") //directly. No echo required
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code expects these two methods:

- the_title()
- the_except()

To return a string so it can be echo'd out.

However they're not returning a string, they're return null or perhaps an empty string. What they do instead is echo the content out directly.

To fix it, do this:

```
echo '<div>';
the_excerpt();
echo '</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats normal! :) "the_" prefix implicitly means that an echo will be done for you automatically, you should use `get_the_title()` instead, when you want to control what to echo with more fine grain control.

See this link for further info: [Wordpress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to control title formatting. You can achieve this through either a filter OR...

`$post->post_title`

the above is direct access to the post title. This will return a string.

using your harness:

```
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="myimage.jpg"></div>
My title<h2></h2>
<h2><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h2>
<p>My excerpt</p><div></div>
```